# Upgraded python but still getting 'TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

```
import ast
def _load_functions(self):
    assert (isinstance(self.ast, ast.Module))
    statements = []
    for child_node in ast.iter_child_nodes(self.ast):
        if isinstance(child_node, ast.FunctionDef):
            statements.append(child_node)
        elif isinstance(child_node, ast.Import):
            statements.append(child_node)
        elif isinstance(child_node, ast.ImportFrom):
            statements.append(child_node)
    self.filtered_module = ast.Module(body=statements)
    code = compile(self.filtered_module, '<ast>', 'exec')
```

- Python 3.9.7
- IPython 8.0.1
- werkzeug 2.0.3

The line `code = compile(self.filtered_module, '<ast>', 'exec')` reported the error.

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. (2) What is "self.filtered_module", how is it created?

Comment: I have put more context in, not sure if this is enough, could you please have another look? @MichaelButscher

Comment: When creating the "ast.Module" add an argument "type_ignores=[]". Some details can be found [here](https://pybit.es/articles/ast-intro/#the-moduletype_ignores-attribute-and-type-comments)